# Spotify search bar api that allows a user to search for artist and receives the artists top 5 albums

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, spotify

I am now receiving an error when clicking the button on the web page.

```
System.Net.WebException
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.



using System;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Task_3
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            button1.Text = "Search";
            string[] hello = {"Hello, World"};
            MainClass.Main(hello);
            MainClass.SetInput(search1.Text);
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            TableRow tRow2 = new TableRow();
            TableCell album1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell artist1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell date1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tracks1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell popularity1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell id1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell album2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell artist2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell date2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tracks2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell popularity2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell id2 = new TableCell();
            album1.Text = "Album Name";
            artist1.Text = "Artist Name";
            date1.Text = "Date of Release";
            tracks1.Text = "Number of Tracks";
            popularity1.Text = "Popularity";
            id1.Text = "ID";
            tRow.Cells.Add(album1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(artist1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(date1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tracks1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(popularity1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(id1);
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
            tRow2.Cells.Add(album2);
            tRow2.Cells.Add(artist2);
            tRow2.Cells.Add(date2);
            tRow2.Cells.Add(tracks2);
            tRow2.Cells.Add(popularity2);
            tRow2.Cells.Add(id2);
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow2);
            album1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            artist1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            date1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            tracks1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            popularity1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            id1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            Table1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            Table1.Visible = true;
            id2.Text = MainClass.getData(2);
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        static string input;
        static string [] data = new string[25];
        public static void fillData(){
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                data[j] = "" + j.ToString();
            }
        }
        public static string getData(int j){
           // fillData();
            return data[j];
           // return input;
        }
        public static void SetInput(string str){
            input = str;
        }
        public string GetInput(){
            return input;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fillData();
            string search = input;//"Muse";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + search + "&type=artist");

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "XXXXXXXX");

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // causing the error on website
            string myResponse = "";
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            string[] idStrings = new string[50];
            int index1;
            for (int i = 0, startIndex = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                idStrings[i] = "";
                index1 = myResponse.IndexOf("id\" : \"", startIndex);
                if (index1 == -1) break;
                else idStrings[i] = myResponse.Substring(index1 + 7, 22);
                startIndex = index1 + 30;
            }
            string id = "4aawyAB9vmq...";
            HttpWebRequest idRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + id);

            idRequest.Method = "GET";
            idRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            idRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            idRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "XXXXXXXXXXX");

            HttpWebResponse idResponse = (HttpWebResponse)idRequest.GetResponse();
            string myIdResponse = "";
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(idResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                myIdResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(myResponse.ToString());

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(idStrings[i]);
            }


        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I commented where the HTTP 500.Error processing request is, however I do not know how to fix it. The code works through terminal but not through the web page...???

I may be writing to much into this and there may be an easier way however I have not worked in an asp.net environment before so I am new.

Any help would be appreciated!

Also if someone can tell me how to go about the next step of taking the input and getting the id from the artist results of search, this would help as well!

Answer (score 1):

Your button has no Onclick event bound to it, so clicking it will never trigger `button1Clicked`.

```
<asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="button1Clicked" />
```

And this line `public static void Main(string[] args)` has no references (as does `GetClientCredentialsAuthToken`) and looks like a Winform method. Are you sure you are not mixing WEBforms and WINforms code?

Comment: Thank you! I made changes to the code above and I have gotten data to the table. Now when I pass in main my code that works in terminal is not working on the webpage.

Comment: First, `Console.WriteLine` is still WINforms code. And when I tried to run your code it gives `(401) Unauthorized` on line `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()`. Which means you are not allowed to make that request. Either you provide the wrong credentials or use the wrong type of authorization (and i've masked the above bearer codes to prevent misuse, should they be authentic)